# Database Postcode Records, Google Maps?

Tags: sql, database, google-maps

Currently I have a website and database solution, however I would like to take 'Postcodes' from the records and place corresponding markers for them on a Google maps view.

Is this possible? And where would I start? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Google Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) to place a map on your webpage.  There is a good code example section.  Markers should be easy to find.

The process of translating a postcode to a map location is called [geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/).  There are code samples here too.  The geocoding API has a usage limit and it takes time to do its work.  SO if you have many postcodes, you might want to cache geocoding results.

There are many, many ways to get postcodes from a database to JavaScript.  If you have an issue there, you'd better ask a more specific question, including the platform and language tag.